# Loading new view from didReceiveLocalNotification

Tags: iphone, view, localnotification

Ive been searching for a solution for hours and my question is really simple.
I have a local notification that fires and i want to load a new view to show the user when the notification has been fired and the user have clicked the "view" button. 
Is this possible and if so, how do i do it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: just to be sure: you want to show a specific view of your app after the user "accept" your local notfication, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your appDelegate put this code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
// show your view here!}
```

this method is called when your app receive the local notification and you can also use the "notif" object to store useful data when you create the notification.

If you have a view MyView and it's xib file (like MyView.xib where you set the main view as MyView class) you can do something like this to load it

In MyView.m add a class method to create a new view from a xib:

```
+ (id) newMyView
{
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
    NSArray *nibArray = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    MyView *me = [nibArray objectAtIndex: 0];
    return me;
}
```

then in the local notification callback you can have something like:

```
MyView *view = [MyView newMyView];
[self.window addSubView:view];
```

Where window is the property you normally have in the app delegate template.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Im aware of the didReceiveLocalNotification in appDelegate. The problem is that i can't figure out how to create a view from there or even switch view to another. I understand that my explaination is hard to understand. I dont know how to better describe my problem.

Comment: See the editing, hope this time I understand what you need... ;)

Comment: This is almost what i need :) If i dont have a nib-file for the view, can i create a view programmetically? This code is usefull for me if i creat a xib, but is it when i do it programmatically? Sorry that ive been missing that part :p

Comment: of course you can do it programmatically! the XIB way allow you to get a nice view easyer, but everything can do by code. Just rememebr to add the view as subview like my last line of code ;)

Comment: thanks alot :) This was very usefull! Ive tried it and it works fine! Im really greatful! :)